# How to assign different index numbers to determined observations?

Tags: r, matrix-indexing

What I want to do is assign a value of 1 to the first 1/3 of observations ofmy data, then a value of 2 to the second 1/3 of observations of my data and finally a value of 3 to the third 1/3 of observations of my data.

Taking into a ccount that my data consists of 30 observations, I did the following code:

```
c1 <- c(rep(1,10),rep(2,10),rep(3,10))
```

which I cbinded to my data

```
gala2 <- cbind(data,c1)
```

Then, for the first 10 observations (my first 1/3), the value of c1 is 1, for the next ten observations (second 1/3) the value of c1 is 2 and for the last ten observations (my third 1/3) the value of c1 is 3.

This works perfectly fine, but I wanted to ask if there is a way to do this in a more "abstract" way. That is, to tell R to assign the value of 1 to the first 1/3 of the data, assign the value of 2 to the second 1/3 and the value of 3 to the third 1/3?

Best regards,

Answer (score 1):

Yes there is, try to take a look to `cut()`. To illustrate a bit try this with your example:

```
cut(yourDataAsNumeric,3,labels=FALSE)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
sort(rep_len(seq(3), length(c1)))
```

where `c1` is your vector.